# PHPMailer send only <p> tag in HTML email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email

My trouble is PHPMailer send email, but include only P tags in message.
Where is my mistake?

```
include 'class.phpmailer.php';
$Mailer = new PHPMailer();
$Mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$Mailer->Body = '<html style="background: #FF0000;"><body><p>dsdgs</p></body></html>';
$Mailer->SetFrom('mailer@stpoisk.ru', 'Иванов Владимир');
$Mailer->AddAddress('mysss2019@gmail.com');
$Mailer->Subject = 'Тема';
$Mailer->IsHTML(true);
$Mailer->Send();
```

In my Gmail account i recieve the html code that i send, but it not rendering correctly, only plain text;

```
Delivered-To: mysss2019@gmail.com
Received: by 10.50.237.35 with SMTP id uz3csp342713igc;
        Wed, 16 Apr 2014 13:03:33 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.112.13.72 with SMTP id f8mr2901958lbc.40.1397678612593;
        Wed, 16 Apr 2014 13:03:32 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <motostz6@appolon0.beget.ru>
Received: from appolon0.beget.ru (appolon0.beget.ru. [91.106.203.74])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id lb6si15770273lab.212.2014.04.16.13.03.32
        for <mysss2019@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 16 Apr 2014 13:03:32 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of motostz6@appolon0.beget.ru designates 91.106.203.74 as permitted sender) client-ip=91.106.203.74;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of motostz6@appolon0.beget.ru designates 91.106.203.74 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=motostz6@appolon0.beget.ru
Received: from motostz6 (Authenticated sender motostz6@appolon0.beget.ru)
    by appolon0.beget.ru with local (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <motostz6@appolon0.beget.ru>)
    id 1WaW3P-0005KN-AD
    for mysss2019@gmail.com; Thu, 17 Apr 2014 00:03:31 +0400
To: mysss2019@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0KLQtdC80LA=?=
Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 00:03:31 +0400
Message-ID: <5f69d9a84b6e6aa939460da74bee0bd9@www.novator18.ru>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
From: motostz6@appolon0.beget.ru
Reply-To: РРІР°РЅРѕРІ Р’Р»Р°РґРёРјРёСЂ <mailer@stpoisk.ru> 
X-Beget-Rewrite: original from 'РРІР°РЅРѕРІ Р’Р»Р°РґРёРјРёСЂ <mailer@stpoisk.ru> '
X-Beget-Rewrite: original reply-to 'РРІР°РЅРѕРІ Р’Р»Р°РґРёРјРёСЂ <mailer@stpoisk.ru> '

<html style="background: #FF0000;"><body><p>dsdgs</p></body></html>
```

Comment: PHPmailer does NOT check emails for contents. It will not filter out html, or validate the html, or clean up the html. It passes on exactly what you gave it. If you're not getting the same thing on the receiving end, then something else is filtering it... not phpmailer.

Comment: May be i have mistake in Content-Type, or setup my $Mailer class, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an ancient version of PHPMailer. [Try something recent](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) from GitHub. That said, that message is formatted OK (it renders fine in Apple Mail), but gmail does nasty things to CSS, and putting a style attribute in the html tag is a bit strange so you will probably have more success setting the background colour using an attribute on the body tag:

```
<html><body bgcolor="#FF0000"><p>dsdgs</p></body></html>
```